# Bootstrap 4 sidebar menu - collapse when resizing Browser

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to adapt the following example:
[Bootstrap 4 Sidebar Menu](https://www.codeply.com/go/8ESO56VMns)

What I am trying to get is to make it work in the same way whether I am collapsing the sidebar with a button or resizing Browser window. Currently, button hides the panel completely, but resizing collapses to icons and before that makes the panel smaller while the toggle button hides it at once. I have played with the sample css but could not get anywhere. Can someone please at least provide a direction to take?

Thanks

Comment: I just found out how to make sidebar's width static when resizing the Browser. But still need to collapse the sidebar with the button to the icons. Just like resizing does.